# Applescript: expected expression but found "/"

Tags: applescript

I'm looking for a script that will save the url's of my open tabs in Safari to a text document, so that I can open them later (its 10+ tabs). I found this script online:

```
[applescript]
tell application "Safari"

--Variables
set windowCount to number of windows
set docText to ""

--Repeat for Every Window
repeat with x from 1 to windowCount
set tabcount to number of tabs in window x

--Repeat for Every Tab in Current Window
repeat with y from 1 to tabcount

--Get Tab Name & URL
set tabName to name of tab y of window x
set tabURL to URL of tab y of window x

set docText to docText & "<a href=" & "\"" & tabURL & "\">" & tabName & "</a>" & linefeed as string
end repeat

end repeat
end tell

--Write Document Text
tell application "TextEdit"
activate
make new document
set the text of the front document to docText
end tell

[/applescript]
```

But when I try to run this I get the error

> Expected expression, but found "/"

and it marks the last line, [/applescript] as being wrong. I've searched for the error but can't seem to find it. anyone got an idea?

Comment: If some answer solves your problem, you can tap the checkmark below vote count of an answer to make it green.

Answer (score 3):

You probably should remove the `[applescript]` and `[/applescript]` lines when you put the script into the AppleScript Editor.

Comment: Thanks! Works prefectly now!

Answer (score 3):

Remove `[applescript]` and `[/applescript]`